# How created watched folder with Automator to auto import new files into itunes?

Tags: macos, itunes, automator

I was wondering if someone could help me with this. This what I'd like to do:

File is downloaded into Folder A, it is automatically imported into itunes and then moved to folder B. This happens automatically anytime a new file appears, I don't have to trigger a script, etc..

Can this be done with automator?

I've tried by making a workflow:
Finder Finder Items
Import Files into Itunes (but it won't import movie files, only audio)

If anyone can help or knows of a little app that do this please let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it better by placing files to the folder `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes` in Finder (or `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes.localized` in Terminal.app) to be automatically added to iTunes without any third party program

Comment: Note that the location depends on locale.  In Danish the folder is `$HOME/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Føj automatisk til iTunes`

Comment: This is nice. Never knew this folder existed. Just a note if you have moved your music library from the default location. The Automatically Add to iTunes needs to be the one inside the relocated Music folder. And not the default.

Answer (score 3):

In Automator, choose the Folder Action Template

[image]