# Automator: How can I monitor a folder, make items process in a specific app?

Tags: finder, automator

I will be feeding images into a folder from my camera as they are taken. When those items enter the folder, I need for them to be opened and processed by an app.

How would I go about monitoring the folder and then making new items open in a specific app? (In this case, the app will be a Photoshop "droplet" app).

I have never used Automator, and I do not know Javascript or anything like that.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How created watched folder with Automator to auto import new files into itunes?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/81709/how-created-watched-folder-with-automator-to-auto-import-new-files-into-itunes)

Comment: It's not directly a duplicate (even if the answers might be very similar).